# Repository Pattern and Find Functionality in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

It is a good pattern to separate the way objects are persisted from the business logic. If I expose how objects are persisted in the database to the business logic, then when I change how these objects are persisted, I will have to change the business logic, making them tightly coupled.

With that being said, suppose that the business logic uses Foo as an object, and suppose that the DAL (using EF) uses FooDbModel as an object for persisting. Building the CRUD operations with the repository pattern is very simple: Get `Foo` object, build `FooDbModel`, do whatever is needed, and build `Foo` back, and return it.

But when `Find` functionality is little more involving. Ideally, I want to do something like:

```
Repository.Find(f => f.Name == "something");
```

where `f` is of type `Foo` (not `FooDbModel`). Is that possible with EF? I don't want to pass `f` where if is of type `FooDbModel` because that is exposing the data persistence to the BL.

Is there a trick to do that?

Comment: Project (`Select`) before filter(`Where`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev The problem with that is that you will have to put all data in DB in memory to do a projection. It is similar to Repo.GetAll().Where(...). This is probably not the best approach unless the db is really tiny. Thanks though.

Comment: Not if you do it on `IQueryable`. Not sure how exactly your methods are structured, but the **implementation** of the `Find` method I see is something like `context.Set<FooDbModel>().Select(m => new Foo { ... }).Where(f => ...)` which should translate to SQL.

Comment: EF already implements the repository pattern, which is treating a data store like an in memory collection, it already hides the db implementation. Implementing another repository on top just leads you to something less functional as you gradually recreate all its functionality as you are finding. People rarely change their persistence mechanisms and when they do a repository won't protect you from the huge scope of the changes.

Comment: @IvanStoev Now I see what you are saying. But then 'f' has to be of type FooDbModel which is not accessible to BL. I don't think there is a way to convert a predict that easy.

Comment: That's the whole point, after `Select` operator `f` is of type `Foo` :) In other words, let EF query translator do the hard work for you.

Comment: @Mant101 You are correct. But if you expose EF objects directly, then if you want to persist similar entities in a nosql db (maybe because of cost or availablility) then you will need to rewrite quite many things in the bl which is  not its concern.

Comment: @IvanStoev You are correct. I am very sorry.

Comment: @Husain if you want to keep you bl separate I would look at something like mediator pattern. Pass simple objects in an out the bl but don't give it a leaky abstraction of your data layer with a repository (IQueryable and expressions leak a lot) . The idea you can build a generic repository that you can swap from a relational db to a nosql db is a fiction, its just wasted effort. YAGNI.

Comment: @Mant101 For the most part, swapping DB types is fiction, specially if the software is written after having requirements, etc. But that's not always the case. If I am writing a software as POC, and I am not sure about how it will evolve, then I have to make it as ignostic as possible with respect to DB, and delay the decision of which DB to use as much as possible. But your point is taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IvanStoev solved the problem.

Basically, I will need to do a select and then a where.

To quote him:

> Not if you do it on IQueryable. Not sure how exactly your methods are structured, but the implementation of the Find method I see is something like context.Set().Select(m => new Foo { ... }).Where(f => ...) which should translate to SQL.